# Unable to set JPanel's Background in my Swing program.

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I set a JPanel as a contentPane of my JFrame.

When I use:

```
jPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

The white color is not applied.

But when I use:

```
jFrame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

It works... I am surprised by this behaviour. It should be the opposite, shouldn't it?

SSCCE:

Here is an SSCCE:

Main Class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window win = new Window();
    }
}
```

Window Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private Container mainContainer = new Container();

    public Window(){
        super();
        this.setTitle("My Paint");
        this.setSize(720, 576);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainContainer.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Doesn't work whereas this.setBackground(Color.WHITE) works
        this.setContentPane(mainContainer);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Container Class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Container extends JPanel {
    public Container() {
        super();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the size of the jpanel? Does it completely fill the content pane?

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I didn't set the size of my jPanel. I thought when you set it as a contentPane, it was automatically the same size as the corresponding jFrame.

Comment: @MarAja: you are correct as contentPane it should fill the GUI. But there are other things in your code that you're not telling or showing us that are affecting your GUI's behavior. We can't help without a more complete picture, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Ok I have just edited my first post to add an SSCCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is very simple include the following line

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

when you override paintComponent.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
```

Now it works perfectly.

You should always do this unless you have a very specific reason to do so .

[PS:Change the colour to red or something darker to notice the difference as sometimes it becomes difficult to differentiate between `JFrame`'s default grey colour and White colour]

Answer (score 1):

With my testcode it works the way you expected it to work:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setSize(new Dimension(20,20));
            p.setLocation(20, 20);

            //comment these lines out as you wish. none, both, one or the other
            p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            f.setContentPane(p);

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);

         }
      }
```

Comment: The user was asking for problem in his specific code,not a working method/code.Anyways you put an alternative.Good.